# How to create a dynamic checkbox from sqlite's data?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a checkbox form like this:
[image]

I don't know how to write the html,template and forms.

The data are loaded from sqlite.

It should have a strategy name.

[image]

Should I use {% for item in object_list %}?

But I don't know how to use it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0):

I find my answer,the html code is below:

```
{% for strategy in strategies%}
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Product_1">
<a href="{% url 'strategy_page' strategy.id %}">{{strategy.algo_name}}</a>
<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Thank you.